# What's the way to define props in vue3 (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue3's defineComponent function, the first generic parameter is Props, so I provide my props type using Typescript interface here. like:

```js
export default defineComponent<{ initial?: number }>({
  setup(props) {
    const count = ref(props.initial ?? 0);
    const increase = () => count.value++;
    const decrease = () => count.value--;
    return { count, increase, decrease };
  }
});
```

But my props are not identified by Vue, it means the code below won't work:

```html
<Counter :initial="5"></Counter>
```

If I define props options in my components like:

```js
export default defineComponent<{ initial?: number }>({
  props: {
    initial: { type: Number, required: false },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const count = ref(props.initial ?? 0);
    const increase = () => count.value++;
    const decrease = () => count.value--;
    return { count, increase, decrease };
  }
});
```

it will occurred type error `TS2769: No overload matches this call.`
And I know if I remove the generic parameter will clean up this error, but the props options is not native Typescript.

Someone know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props are a Vue runtime construct and can't be inferred from TypeScript type definitions (there are things like default values, validators, etc associated with props). You'll have to define them using the `props` option as the API expects. To provide strong type definitions for your props use `PropType` to [annotate your props](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props).